# Coq's mathematical proof language: Rewriting in if condition

Tags: coq

I'm trying to learn Coq's mathematical proof language, but I ran into some trouble trying to prove something that I reduced to the following silly statement:

```
Lemma foo: forall b: bool, b = true -> (if b then 0 else 1) = 0.
```

Here's my attempt:

```
proof.
  let b: bool.
  let H: (b = true).
```

At this point the proof state is:

```
  b : bool
  H : b = true
  ============================
  thesis := 
   (if b then 0 else 1) = 0
```

Now I want to rewrite the `if` condition `b` to `true` in order to be able to prove the thesis. However, both a "small step" of

```
  have ((if b then 0 else 1) = (if true then 0 else 1)) by H.
```

and a "bigger step" of

```
  have ((if b then 0 else 1) = 0) by H.
```

fail with `Warning: Insufficient justification.` I don't think there's anything wrong with rewriting in the condition, as the normal `rewrite -> H` tactic will do the same.

I can also get this to work without problems by wrapping the `if` in a function:

```
Definition ite (cond: bool) (a b: nat) := if cond then a else b.
Lemma bar: forall b: bool, b = true -> (ite b 0 1) = 0.
proof.
  let b: bool. let H: (b = true).
  have (ite b 0 1 = ite true 0 1) by H. thus ~= 0.
end proof.
```

This is not very nice, of course. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way to rescue my original proof? Is this just a shortcoming of the implementation of the mathematical proof language?

I note that there is a possibly related example in Section 11.3.3 of the manual (at https://coq.inria.fr/doc/Reference-Manual013.html):

```
  a := false : bool
  b := true : bool
  H : False
  ============================
  thesis :=
  if b then True else False

Coq <  reconsider thesis as True.
```

But I don't know how to get the `b := true` part into the context.

Comment: I don't use Coq, but I do know the Calculus of Constructions: the equality type was simply an expression of Leibniz equality encoded using 2-order polymorphism and dependent quantification over properties. This allowed you to, given any lambda-abstraction λ(x:A)t :A->B and equality witness p: a0=a1 to infer t[x:=a0]=t[x:=a1] - the proof construction you need is just p λ(x:A)t. Unfortunately, I think Coq abandoned using this representation of equality types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `per cases` on `b` (see [sect. 11.3.12](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual013.html#sec519)):

```
Lemma foo:
  forall b: bool, b = true -> (if b then 0 else 1) = 0.
proof.
  let b : bool.
  per cases on b.
    suppose it is true. thus thesis.
    suppose it is false. thus thesis.
  end cases.
end proof.
Qed.
```

I also tried to recreated the proof state of your reference manual example, you could use `define` for that:

```
Lemma manual_11_3_3 :
  if false then True else False ->
  if true then True else False.
proof.
  define a as false.
  define b as true.
  assume H : (if a then True else False).
  reconsider H as False.
  reconsider thesis as True.
Abort.
```

Comment: I'm provisionally "accepting" this as it might be the best way to go even if it's not the rewriting I had hoped for (and that I still think should be allowed).
The `define` does put a `b` in the context in my example but renames the original `b` to `b0`. It doesn't let me exploit the known fact that `b` is true. So that doesn't seem to be the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: (1) Yes, it's just a workaround. It seems that people don't use the declarative language and the behavior you've observed doesn't boost its popularity. (2) Indeed, `define` is not useful in `foo` -- I added it in respond to "I don't know how to get the  `b := true` part into the context". Basically, `define` works like the `set` tactic.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the keyword `proof` enters into a proof mode that is declarative. By constrast, the keyword `Proof` enters into a proof mode that is imperative. In this second case we can prove it easily as follows.

```
Lemma foo: forall b: bool, b = true -> (if b then 0 else 1) = 0.                                     
Proof.                                                                                              
  intros b H.                                                                                       
  rewrite H.                                                                                        
  reflexivity.                                                                                      
Qed.
```

In the first case I do not have an answer. I tried a number of approaches that were similar to yours but found the same problem again and again. Perhaps someone who is more familiar with declarative proofs can give a full answer. Please let us know if you find the solution!

Comment: Yes, this "declarative mode" is what Chapter 11 of the Coq manual calls the "mathematical proof language". I like this style of proving, which I'm familiar with from having worked with Isabelle/HOL. That's why I specifically want to learn it now; I already know the tactics language and know that this proof is trivial ;-)

Comment: That makes sense. I'm glad Anton could help. It's a shame that this simple feature of the declarative language seems not to work directly!